# Extjs - How to extend a Sprite?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sprite, draw, extend

Im trying to create a custom Sprite, a donut like figure and for that im extending the Sprite class.

Im getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" on the line

```
 var realPath = this["getPath" + sprite.type](sprite);
```

Here's my class:

```
Ext.define('Project.view.Donut', {
extend:  'Ext.draw.Sprite' ,
alias: 'widget.donut',


constructor: function(){

    var me = this;
    me.callParent(arguments);
}});
```

My controller:

```
        var me = this;
    var canvas = me.ownerCmp.down('container[name=canvas]');

    canvas.add({
        xtype: 'draw',
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        items: [{
                type: 'donut',
                radius: 90,
                x: 50,
                y: 50,
                fill: 'blue'
    }]
    });
```

Comment: You should provide more information. What is inside the Project.view.Donut class? What are you trying to do with realPath and what does the keyword this reference? If you want to create your Donut, then a call to Ext.create('donut') should suffice.

Comment: My code was only this. But i solved  this problem using a surface and joining sprites to create a custom shape